# error:AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'db_type' when run "python manage.py syncdb" in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, neo4j, neo4django

I am working on a django project and I have two databases "mysql " and " neo4j" .I install `neo4django` package and change the setting.py like below:

setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'mylifetime',                     
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '',                      
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
NEO4J_DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':7474,
        'ENDPOINT':'/db/data'
    }
}
```

and my models currently have only neo4j models:

models.py:

```
from neo4django.db import models


class User(models.NodeModel):
    ...
    #my User models ...
    ....
class Post(models.NodeModel):
    ...
    #my Post models
    ...
```

when i run this command `python manage.py syncdb` I got error :

```
$ python ../manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'db_type'
```

When I use only MySql models I don't see the errors and tables will create successfully.
where Am I wrong ?
thanks

EDIT:
when I write `python manage.py syncdb --traceback` I see below :

```
Creating tables ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 255, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 91, in handle_noargs
    sql, references = connection.creation.sql_create_model(model, self.style, seen_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 50, in sql_create_model
    col_type = f.db_type(connection=self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4django-0.1.8-py2.7.egg/neo4django/utils.py", line 303, in __getattr__
    return getattr(target, name)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'db_type'
```

Comment: see this: https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/issues/105

Comment: thanks.i don't insert `DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['neo4django.utils.Neo4djangoIntegrationRouter']` following in the [neo4j_docs](https://neo4django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html) in the settings.py.but really what is it ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `--traceback` option to `manage.py` to see a full stack trace of the exception you get.

Comment: I didn't know this option exists! +1

Answer (score 2):

As noted [in the docs](https://neo4django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html), if you want to run against Neo4j *and* a relational DB, you need to add `neo4django.utils.Neo4djangoIntegrationRouter` to your `DATABASE_ROUTERS` in settings.py.